# Jekyll Conversion Error With Bourbon

Tags: css, sass, jekyll, bourbon

Whenever I try to `bundle exec jekyll build/serve` I get the following error:

```
 Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'css/main.scss':
                    Undefined variable: "$output-bourbon-deprecation-warnings". on line 20
jekyll 3.6.0 | Error:  Undefined variable: "$output-bourbon-deprecation-warnings". on line 20
```

I'm not even sure where to look, because this variable doesn't appear in the css/main.scss file.

Code for the css/main.scss file:

```
---
# Only the main Sass file needs front matter (the dashes are enough)
---
@charset "utf-8";
@import "variables";

// TOOLS
@import "reset";
@import "normalize";
@import "bourbon/bourbon";
@import "neat/neat";

// GLOBAL
@import "base";
@import "layout";

// COMPONENTS
@import "header";
@import "footer";
@import "carousel";
@import "post-index";

// PAGE
@import "posts";

// CUSTOM
@import "custom";
```

I believe that the main use of it is for a prefixer. When I try to comment out bourbon entirely I get more errors. I've also tried removing and then reinstalling the gems.

Comment: What theme are you using and how did you integrate bourbon into your Jekyll installation?

Comment: I didn't install the theme but am now tasked with pushing blog updates. There's no documentation as to how it was made, but this is what I can gather from the files:

We are using [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) components for the carousel, as well as a program called Neat for the grid. All gems were installed with gitbash into our dropbox, which is where we push to the server. The files were originally created on a Mac, and I'm on PC Windows 10. The lone file we have under boubon-> css3 is _calc.scss.  In the main bourbon folder we have an bourbon.scss with @import info.

Comment: Please provide some code. A repository url is better.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how correctly the original theme you're using was configured, this is likely due to the gemfile not being locked down tight enough to the point that it allowed breaking changes.

Add the following to your SCSS file:

```
$output-bourbon-deprecation-warnings: false;
```

This must be added **before** `@import boutbon;`.

Comment: Here is the associated documentation for reference http://bourbon.io/docs/#output-bourbon-deprecation-warnings